# CREATE New Table from existing tables in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables that doesn't have primary keys. These 2 tables have same number of rows. I want to create a new table from getting some columns from table1 and some columns from table 2. I want to combine first row from table1 and first row from table2.
Below is example

**TABLE1**

```
ACOL1 ACOL2 ACOL3
A1 A2 A3
B1 B2 B3
C1 C2 C3
```

**TABLE2**

```
BCOL1 BCOL2 BCOL3
11 12 13
21 22 23
31 32 33
```

**COMBINED_TABLE**

```
ACOL1 BCOL2 BCOL3
A1 12 13
B1 22 23
C1 32 33
```

I tried below query but no luck. It gives below error:
**Query :**

```
create table COMBINED_TABLE 
AS 
select a.ACOL1, b.BCOL2, b.BCOL3 
from (select ACOL1,rownum from TABLE1) a, 
     (select BCOL2, BCOL3, rownum from TABLE2) b 
WHERE a.rownum = b.rownum
```

**Error :** ORA-01747:"invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `rownum` as a column name, giving it an alias solves the problem

```
create table COMBINED_TABLE 
AS 
select a.ACOL1, b.BCOL2, b.BCOL3 
from (select ACOL1,rownum rn from TABLE1) a, 
     (select BCOL2, BCOL3, rownum rn from TABLE2) b 
WHERE a.rn = b.rn
```

Comment: Thank you very much Maxim, you saved the day.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table combined_table
as
select a.acol1, b.bcol2, b.bcol3
from (
  select acol1, row_number() over (order by acol1) as rn
  from table1
) a 
  join (
    select bcol2, bcol3, row_number() over (order by bcol1) as rn
    from table2
  ) b on a.rn = b.rn
```

Using `row_number()` is more robust than `rownum` as you can actually define what "last" or "first" row means (those terms don't have a meaning unless some order is defined).

When you define an `order by` in the window function the resulting join is more stable as the row numbers are always calculated the same way (which is *not* the case with `rownum`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE table1a (
  acol1 NUMBER,
  acol2 NUMBER,
  acol3 NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE table2a (
  bcol1 NUMBER,
  bcol2 NUMBER,
  bcol3 NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO table1a VALUES (1, 2, 3);
INSERT INTO table1a VALUES (4, 5, 6);

INSERT INTO table2a VALUES (10, 20, 30);
INSERT INTO table2a VALUES (40, 50, 60);

CREATE TABLE combined_table (ct1, ct2, ct3) AS
  SELECT a.acol1, b.bcol2, b.bcol3
    FROM
      (SELECT a.*, rownum AS rn FROM table1a a) a,
      (SELECT b.*, rownum AS rn FROM table2a b) b
  WHERE a.rn = b.rn
;
```